# Site freeze when I start the admin portion

Tags: php, debugging, magento, caching, reindex

The site is really fast. I have created a script to check every second what the speed of the website.
The results.

```
FAST - 17:41:54: 0.287875890732
FAST - 17:41:55: 0.311651945114
FAST - 17:41:57: 0.264428138733
FAST - 17:41:58: 0.304912805557
FAST - 17:42:00: 0.321930885315
FAST - 17:42:01: 0.29382109642
FAST - 17:42:02: 0.289844989777
FAST - 17:42:04: 0.278220891953
FAST - 17:42:05: 0.31251001358
FAST - 17:42:07: 0.285416126251
FAST - 17:42:08: 0.290918111801
FAST - 17:42:09: 0.332083940506
FAST - 17:42:11: 0.266509056091
FAST - 17:42:12: 0.281701803207
FAST - 17:42:14: 0.275447845459
```

I'm very happy with the speed.
But I have persistent problem and I have no idea where to look to fix this problem.
The moment a start the admin the site totally freezes.

The results

```
SLOW - 20:50:56: 2.04331302643
SLOW - 20:51:10: 12.8588819504
SLOW - 20:51:23: 12.3065569401
FAST - 20:51:25: 0.452680110931
FAST - 20:51:27: 0.337702989578
FAST - 20:51:28: 0.332473993301
SLOW - 20:51:42: 12.5140118599
SLOW - 20:53:43: 120.119220972
FAST - 20:53:45: 0.508615016937
FAST - 20:53:47: 0.520901203156
SLOW - 20:54:05: 16.9637360573
SLOW - 20:55:20: 73.9818410873
SLOW - 20:55:36: 14.3260159492
SLOW - 20:56:08: 30.5557489395
SLOW - 20:57:51: 102.450763941
FAST - 20:57:53: 0.282537937164
FAST - 20:57:55: 0.493069887161
FAST - 20:57:56: 0.322154998779
SLOW - 20:57:59: 2.06928992271
SLOW - 20:58:03: 2.24757194519
SLOW - 20:58:06: 2.02194190025
FAST - 20:58:10: 1.7101111412
```

As you can see I have some loads that are more then 100 sec. The strange thing is that I get no errors at all.

The site is running on dedicated server with memcache and apc. What I have already done to try to fix this problem.

- Flush cache/Memcache APC.
- Restart the server
- Reindex all data
- Checking for bugs
- Try some debug tools to find the problem

I have no idea where a have to search to find the problem.

The only thing what I have not done is remove all the sessions in the database.
Is there difference between sessions on the frontend and sessions in the admin?

Are there any tools/extensions to find the problem so I can fix it?

Comment: Start by using the built in profiler: https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=17&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=magento+profiler

Comment: Do you use Enterprise or Community? Also how about your Mysql configuration? Is it dedicated cluster or hosted on the same machine?

Comment: At AlanStorm -> I have use it. But i can not find any critique issues. I check this on a staging environment and can nog regenerate the problem on staging environment. The problem only happens on the live 
environment. So it is not easy to check what the problem is.

Comment: At IvanChepurnyi -> We are running Magento Enterprise 1.10.1.1. The mysql configuration is running on Dedicated cluster. Do you think it's has something to do with migration between the mysql servers?